# android studio / intellij idea goto line number

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

In Eclipse, if I type cmd+L, it opens a dialog for me to enter a line number and it takes me there in the code. How do I do the same thing in Android Studio? Instead of having to scroll each time I need a specific line number.

Answer (score 58):

Use Command + L for Mac OS X.

[IntellijIDEA default keymap reference](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard_Mac.pdf)
Here is the IntellijIDEA default keymap reference. This is applicable to Android Studio too.

You can also find the document from Android Studio -> Help -> Default Keymap Reference

Answer (score 56):

The shortcut to go to a specific line and/or column number is: <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>

[image: Android Studio Go to Line dialog box] ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20220706090257/https://i.stack.imgur.com/VL2p0.png))

Examples:

1. Go to line 6
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. Go to line 6 and column 8
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>:</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Go to column 4 on the current line
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd><kbd>:</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Shortcut References:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> = H̲elp -> Default K̲eymap Reference
- [IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20220620025638/https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf))
- [Android Studio Shortcuts You Need the Most](http://javapapers.com/android/android-studio-shortcuts-you-need-the-most/) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20220706085507/https://javapapers.com/android/android-studio-shortcuts-you-need-the-most/)) • [PDF version](https://javapapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Android-Studio-Shortcuts-You-Need-the-Most.pdf) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506180737/https://javapapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Android-Studio-Shortcuts-You-Need-the-Most.pdf))

Answer (score 26):

The shortcut to go to a particular line number on Android Studio is

**On Mac**
 : Cmd + L

**On Linux**
 : Ctrl + L

**On Windows**
 : Ctrl + G

After this key in the line number in the dialog box that pops up.There is an option to insert the column number as well, but it is not necessary.

Answer (score 5):

- If you are in the specific file,

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>. And insert the line You wanted. If you want to go to a specific column of the `lineNo` you can insert `lineNo`:`columnNo`.

[image]

- If you are in some file and you want to navigate into some line of a some other file,

You can simply use default navigation shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>, and insert `fileName` : `lineNo`.

***NOTE***: **You don't need to insert the whole name of the file, some text that enables intellij to uniquely identify your file would be good enough. Your input text might turn into red color. But it works. :)**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For Windows users shortcut is: Ctrl + G

Answer (score 0):

You can simply jump to any file at any line number using this shortcut.

Press Double Shift, then in the popped window, just write your file's name [space] and line number

for Example:
(Press Double Shift) => MainActivity 314

it will jump you to 314th line in MainActivity. if the line is exceeding the last line, the last line will be located.