# go to line shortcuts keyboard for android studio on mac

Tags: android-studio

Todays i am really confused about the shortcuts keyboard on mac,here is my scrap image from android studio preferences:
[image]

there is no such shortcuts,and i have looked some comments about this question,somebody said Ctrl + G should make sense,but i tried and not work.because i really like this function in eclipse and can not find it on android studio,every time i want to go to specific line is too troublesome.thank you!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure because I don't own a Mac, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31932176/6166978) they say it's Command + L for Mac OSX. Hope it works :)

Comment: wow! i forget the eclipse shortcuts of this function is also ctrl+L,thanks you

Comment: Don't thank me, thank the other answer. You're welcome! :)

Comment: If you ever find this, remember the other answer above from @Matt, Arctic Fox version 2020.3.1 changed the command. Check his answer

Comment: The answer above by @Matt also reminds us that it is possible to change the shortcut via Settings > Preferences (Window) > Main Menu > Navigate > Go to Line:Column

Answer (score 1):

As of Arctic Fox version 2020.3.1 the keyboard shortcut for goto line/column is Command + G.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per Android Studio Electric Eel version the short-cut is **Command + L** .

[image]